# Codeigniter error Message using ion_auth: Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$uid

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I got this error message when running PHP Code Igniter project using `ion_auth`:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$uid

Filename: models/ion_auth_model.php

Line Number: 1715

Array
(
    [identity] => adedoyinadekunle3@gmail.com
    [username] => adekunleadedoyin
    [email] => adedoyinadekunle3@gmail.com
    [uid] => oaT2dH1jIG
    [user_id] => 126
    [old_last_login] => 1438757260
```

this is my code

```
$query = $this->db->select('username, email, uid, password, active, last_login, id')
                          ->where($this->identity_column, $identity)
                          ->limit(1)
                          ->order_by('id', 'desc')
                          ->get($this->tables['user_reg']);

$user = $query->row();
return $this->set_session($user);
```

my `set_session` function is given below:

```
public function set_session($user)
{

    $this->trigger_events('pre_set_session');

    $session_data = array(
        'identity'             => $user->{$this->identity_column},
        'username'             => $user->username,
        'email'                => $user->email,
        'uid'                  => $user->uid,
        'user_id'              => $user->id, //everyone likes to overwrite id so we'll use user_id
        'old_last_login'       => $user->last_login
    );
    return $session_data;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in my new `ion_auth` ?

Comment: i think there is no colum named as `UID` in your user table try instead `ID` as colum name

Comment: i added the uid column, as u can see it retrives the uid value   [uid] => oaT2dH1jIG  but dont no why am still getting the error when i try to store the UID in a session

Answer (score 0):

Try This as your $query,

```
$query = $this->db->select($this->identity_column.', id, username, email, last_login')
                          ->where($this->identity_column, get_cookie('identity'))
                          ->where('remember_code', get_cookie('remember_code'))
                          ->limit(1)
                          ->get($this->tables['users']);
```

And Set Your $session_data as,

```
$session_data = array(
            'identity'             => $user->{$this->identity_column},
            'username'             => $user->username,
            'email'                => $user->email,
            'user_id'              => $user->id, //everyone likes to overwrite id so we'll use user_id
            'old_last_login'       => $user->last_login
        );
```

Comment: your query works perfect but wen i add a new field 'uid' the error is thesame